# How do I compile and run a Groovy AST?

Tags: compiler-construction, groovy

I've made a basic Groovy AST like this:

```
BinaryExpression plus = new BinaryExpression(new ConstantExpression(5), new Token(Types.PLUS, "+", 0, 0), new ConstantExpression(100));
```

I'm not 100% sure if this does what I think it does, but I can't test it because I don't know how to get this into the proper phase of the compiler. I tried a `GroovyShell`, but that wants a `GroovyCodeSource`, so I can't use this AST.

How do I compile and run this AST?